# Remove &quot from json using laravel

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

Hello I wanted to know how to use blade variable in javascript.
here is my query in laravel

```
$users=json_encode(DB::table('ledger')->select('name','openingbalance')->get());
```

I'm trying to access this in my javascript file like shown below

```
var users ="{{ $users }}";
```

and I get output as shown below:

```
[
      {&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Harsh&quot;,&quot;openingbalance&quot;:&quot;5755.00&quot;},      
      {&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Harh&quot;,&quot;openingbalance&quot;:&quot;-12000.00&quot;},
      {&quot;name&quot;:&quot;gfgfhgf&quot;,&quot;openingbalance&quot;:&quot;-333.00&quot;}
]
```

I wanted to know how to remove &quot so i get a perfect json to use.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You're escaping the data with `{{ }}` automatically in Laravel 5. Use `{!! $users !!}` instead.

Comment: Yep {!! $users !!} worked @JoelHinz which means that i can use this as a json file right?

Comment: Sure. And if you ever want to send just json in the response, no html or javascript or anything, have a look at http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#json-responses :)

Comment: any Idea on how to store {!! $user !!} output  in an array and convert in into associative array further?

Comment: Should work just tacking on `->toArray()` after the `get()` call.

Comment: Nice xss vulnerability, now you can use `@json($users)`

Answer (score 4):

#### Rendering JSON

Sometimes you may pass an array to your view with the intention of rendering it as *JSON* in order to initialize a *JavaScript* variable. For example:

```php
<script>
    var app = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
</script>
```

However, instead of manually calling `json_encode`, you may use the `@json` Blade directive. The `@json` directive accepts the same arguments as PHP's `json_encode` function. By default, the `@json` directive calls the `json_encode` function with the `JSON_HEX_TAG`, `JSON_HEX_APOS`, `JSON_HEX_AMP`, and `JSON_HEX_QUOT` flags:

```php
<script>
    var app = @json($array);

    var app = @json($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
</script>
```

> You should only use the `@json` directive to render existing variables as JSON. The Blade templating is based on regular expressions and attempts to pass a complex expression to the directive may cause unexpected failures.

Source: [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-json)

Answer (score 3):

in new laravel version you can use now @json($users)

Comment: It would be nice, if you shows exactly how this code should be after the implementation you suggested. This will improve your answer.

Comment: Can you pinpoint me to the right link, I cant find the documentation..